# get values from next row in pandas df and insert to previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large q/a dataset, which always contains 3 rows per unique id /they are already grouped.

| id | from | to | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | max |  | hi |
| 1 | charls | max | hey ! |
| 1 | alex | max | howdi ! |
| 2 | sandy |  | hi |
| 2 | sandy |  | hey !?! |
| 2 | sam | sandy | jeah ? |

I want only the text values  and compress  each three rows into one / drop the other two rows.

| id | author_text_1 | author_text_2 | author_text_3 | reply_text_1 | reply_text_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi |  |  | hey ! | howdi ! |
| 2 | hi | hey !?! |  | jeah ? |  |

I tried for each group of 3 rows, to drop the last two rows and add the values from each 'text' column to the corresponding 'author_text' and 'reply_text' columns.

I am struggling with implementing the case that the author could make the question post and 2 more posts which would fill the three rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the column as the new key for `pivot`

```
df['key'] = np.where(df.to.isna(),'author_text_','reply_text_')
df['key'] += df.groupby(['id','key']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
out = df.pivot('id','key','text')
Out[254]: 
key author_text_1 author_text_2 reply_text_1 reply_text_2
id                                                       
1          NaN hi           NaN         hey!       howdi!
2              hi        hey!?!        jeah?          NaN
```